# Will Pages/Keynote/Numbers be free for old macs?

Tags: mac-appstore, iwork, macos, price

Will Pages/Keynote/Numbers (ex. iWork) be free for old macs?

Comment: Are you interested in old Macs that had iWork installed as a paid product or old Macs that didn't ever own iWork?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that everyone that owns an older copy of iWork for iOS gets a free upgrade whether or not your version came from a retail CD or the Mac App Store.

If you don't already own iWork - you will have to pay for either a new Mac or the apps piecemeal on the App Store.

The above summary is my understanding of this MacWorld article that includes calls with Apple Press relations and an "on-the-record" confirmation that all owners of iWork should get free upgrades despite some glitches in the initial roll out today.

- http://www.macworld.com/article/2056159/what-you-need-to-know-about-apples-free-apps-policy.html

Comment: "Some users (including yours truly) are reporting issues where the Mac App Store doesn’t recognize their copies; when they click on an iLife or iWork app’s price, they receive the following alert: “[App] is already installed and was not purchased from the Mac App Store. Do you want to buy [app]?” Macworld spoke with an Apple spokesperson who noted that there’s currently an issue with some legacy customers, and the company is working on a fix." - This is the same issue I am seeing, although I keep reading conflicting information. I guess I will just wait and see how it is resolved.

Comment: @Dave I luckily didn't get that error. I have iWork 09 in a subfolder of /Applications and they came from a retail CD install before I upgraded to Mavericks. I just had to go to purchased and click Download.

Comment: Mine are also installed in a sub-folder called iWork '09, and I installed from a retail CD. I'm not sure why the MAS isn't seeing them though.

Comment: On my machine, existing pre-Mac App Store installations of iWork 09 weren't recognised as installed versions suitable for upgrading to the new and latest App Store  versions until I upgraded the OS to Mavericks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to upgrades for users of existing/previous installs of iWork, it has been shown that the logic that handles identifying whether you are eligible for an upgrade does not take into account whther your install was a trial or retail edition.  In some cases, users with a trial version installed have found that upgrades were provided.  It should be noted that the trial versions are no longer available for download officially.

Answer (score 0):

No. It can be downloaded for free only for Macs purchased on or after October 1, 2013 ([source](http://www.apple.com/mac/pages/)).